# I can't make sidebar not floating right of content

Tags: html, css, sidebar

I don't know how to make my sidebar on the right in css? There's many wrong and idk where the wrong at. Please correct and make sure the picture be background of sidebar.
html:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: Perpetua, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #333;
  background: #86d8bc url(gambar/seni.png) repeat-x top;
}

a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #dd0034;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
}

a:active,
a:hover {
  color: #990099;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#debar {
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 15px 22px 15px 24px;
  background: url(gambar/debar.jpg);
}
```

```html
<center>
  <h3> Tour Akhir Pekan </h3> <b> Liburan gak pake bethal <p> Ribet dan Mahal </b> </p>
  <div id="debar">
    <div class="debar_top"> </div>
  </div>
  <P style="border:solid 1px #123; width:900px; height: 30px; padding: 15px; margin:0; text-align:justify;line-height:23px; color: black;font-size: 18px"> Bingung Pilih Habiskan Waktu Dimana Saat Liburan? <br> <a href=""> Klik</a> untuk Referensi </br>
    <h3 style="border:solid 1px #aab; width:900px; padding: 15px; -moz-border-radius: 15px; -khtml-border-radius: 15px; -webkit-border-radius:15px; margin:2; text-align:justify;line-height:50px; color: black;font-size: 18px">Pesona Alam Indonesia yang wajib untuk dijelajahi! </h3>
    <h4 style="border:solid 1px violet; width:900px; padding: 15px; -moz-border-radius: 15px; -khtml-border-radius: 15px; -webkit-border-radius:15px; margin:5; text-align:justify;line-height:50px; color: black;font-size: 18px">Hotel di Indonesia dengan Pemandangan yang Menakjubkan</h4>
</center>
```

Comment: FWIW, you're using some outdated markup like [`<center>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) and [`bgcolor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body#attr-bgcolor) that have been depreciated and may stop working at any time.

Comment: sorry idk:( because im a newbie, can you tell me what i should use?

Comment: For centering you have a few options. The two most popular are; `text-align: center;` which will center child elements that are _inline_ and auto margins. Auto margins require a width to be set. As far as `bgcolor` use CSS `background-color`. [Check out these examples](https://jsfiddle.net/b2w5dLd1/). There's a few other ways to center too but I'll let you discover those on your own as you're a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend having a `main` container, a `section` child container for content and a `aside` container for the sidebar content. The HTML you've applied seems to be from a very old specification (you've included things like the `center` element and `bgcolor` property, which are no longer used). I also suggest that you [read up on new HTML5 elements](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp) to be more semantic.

```css
main{
  height:400px;
}

main > section{
  width:80%;
  float:left;
  height:100%;
  background:blue;
}

main > aside{
  width:20%;
  float:left;
  height:100%;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section></section>
  <aside></aside>
</main>
```

Comment: I only have 3 days to complete this project. and I'm a newbie. can you tell me how i can change all with HTML5 in 3 days? :(

Comment: There isn't much HTML to change, just put your content within either the `section` or `aside` and you should be done!

Comment: @mas what's _"all HTML?"_ If you're talking about the code in your question, surely you can update that to this solution in 3 days.

Comment: ooooh sorry i didn't read carefully and thank you so much for your suggestion @fauxserious no i think when him say HTML5 i need to change all:( i absolutely wrong sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try this, don't use fix width value...

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: Perpetua, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #333;
  background: #86d8bc url(gambar/seni.png) repeat-x top;
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #dd0034;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
}

a:active,
a:hover {
  color: #990099;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.right-block {
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
}

.left-block {
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
}

#debar {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 15px 22px 15px 24px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-block">
  <center>
    <h3> Tour Akhir Pekan </h3> <b> Liburan gak pake bethal <p> Ribet dan Mahal </b> </p>
    <P style="border:solid 1px #123; height: 30px; padding: 15px; margin:0; text-align:justify;line-height:23px; color: black;font-size: 18px"> Bingung Pilih Habiskan Waktu Dimana Saat Liburan? <br> <a href=""> Klik</a> untuk Referensi </br>
      <h3 style="border:solid 1px #aab; padding: 15px; -moz-border-radius: 15px; -khtml-border-radius: 15px; -webkit-border-radius:15px; margin:2; text-align:justify;line-height:50px; color: black;font-size: 18px">Pesona Alam Indonesia yang wajib untuk dijelajahi! </h3>
      <h4 style="border:solid 1px violet; padding: 15px; -moz-border-radius: 15px; -khtml-border-radius: 15px; -webkit-border-radius:15px; margin:5; text-align:justify;line-height:50px; color: black;font-size: 18px">Hotel di Indonesia dengan Pemandangan yang Menakjubkan</h4>
  </center>
</div>
<div class="right-block">
  <div id="debar">
    <div class="debar_top"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```